# Text in table with max-width td is getting cut off in IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, css

I have a simple table.  The first column has max-width set at 15px.  It is design to hold a small icon.  I have a few summary rows at the bottom of the table.  In on of those rows, I have some long text in that first, small width column.  I want the entire text to overflow beyond the TD width.  I have this working in all browsers except IE7.

I have a jsfiddle set up at http://jsfiddle.net/sweimer/A96Bx/4/.  Open it in IE7 and you will see the text cuts off in the bottom of the first column.  All other browsers show as desired.

Thanks in advance for your time.

scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `colspan` attribute which says, "I want this cell to span x columns in my table," and set it to "5" since your table has 5 columns in total.

```
<td class="icoColumn noWrap" colspan="5">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
max-width:15px;
min-width:15px;
```